# meaning of 蓮も好きなんだから

Tags: meaning

> 「あぁっ しかもあんな強引にされちゃったりして」
>
> 「もぉ…　**蓮も好きなんだから**」

What does 蓮も好きなんだから mean in the above?

To me it's ambiguous and could mean "I also love you", "you also love me", or that he also loves something else.

Can anyone help me understand?

Comment: Who are the characters? Who is saying which sentence? What are the circumstances of the story?

Comment: 危ないですね・・下ネタ？というかアダルトコンテント？になるんじゃないですかね・・

Comment: @sazarando What are you talking about?  That is more than enough context (if you really know Japanese)!

Comment: @l'électeur How so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`person + も + 好き` (with a target unsaid) is a euphemistic and idiomatic phrase meaning "[person] is a lecher". Basically it means "Oh, you (=蓮) also love ****", where **** is a certain type of activity, not a person, which is unsaid because saying it would be explicit.

This idiom is particularly well-known as a part of [加藤茶](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cha_Kat%C5%8D)'s signature gag, [ちょっとだけよ](http://dic.pixiv.net/a/%E3%81%A1%E3%82%87%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A0%E3%81%91%E3%82%88).

Sometimes this phrase is used with a bit pejorative/ridiculing nuance referring to someone with any other extraordinary taste/hobby. For example:

> 彼は週末になると山に登っているよ。**彼も好きだね**。(or あいつも好きだな, etc)